# Write to windows directory(virtual store) with non admin user

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, virtualstore

I writing an interface for legacy application which reads data from windows directory.

So i need to write data into windows directory. (Windows 8 operating system)

I am using below code to get the windows folder path to write the file.

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "test.txt");
```

As i read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756960.aspx), if we run application, as normal user it writes data into virtual store windows folder, but it seems it not working. I am getting access denied error.

My application build with x86 platform.

Something I am missing or any constraints for window 8 OS.

Please assist, many thanks in advance.

Comment: add write/modify permission to the windows folder for the user.

Comment: I think, but I don't know for sure, but I think windows 8 may have removed the virtual store redirection by default. It only re-enables it if the exe is running in compatibility mode. Once again, I think, but I am not sure. Try enabling [compatibility mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/older-programs-compatible-version-windows) and see if that makes it start working.

Comment: No I tried with compatibility mode as well, it does not seems to working on windows 8 :-(

Comment: Just how legacy is this application? Writing to the Windows directory was considered taboo even in the Windows 3 days... I'd say your *best* bet would be to write a shim for the application that intercepted its requests for files in the Windows directory and redirected them to a more appropriate location. That way, you don't compromise the integrity of your entire system just to make one app work. (If you didn't care about that, you'd just run the old version of Windows where this app worked originally.)

Comment: If you read the MSDN article carefully it warns that "Virtualization is implemented to improve application compatibility problems for applications running as a standard user on Windows Vista. Developers must not rely on virtualization being present in subsequent versions of Windows."

Comment: I agree to point but there is requirement and we need to do so.

I am only concerned about is, why file virtualization not working on windows 8? Is something I am missing or what else?

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with the requirement than with programming. Check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg

Comment: I have a vague suspicion that virtual store redirection only happens if the application *doesn't* have a manifest.  I don't know if that's possible with .NET.  You may have to write your application in plain C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in manifest file default comments provided.
it says,

```
<!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
```

So you need to add the manifest file and remove **requestedExecutionLevel** node from xml or from project properties -> Application -> Icon and manifest -> under Manifest set

```
Create application without a manifest
```

It has solved my problem.

Thanks,